# Howcome there is current flowing through the gate of this transistor?

Tags: transistors, mosfet, circuit-analysis, integrated-circuit

I have a few conceptual questions:

1. If there wasn't Rg (Resistor between gate and drain), would Vin = Vout then?
2. For small signal analysis, current can flow through the gate (AC) if there's a voltage source connected to it, right?

[image]

Comment: *"If there wasn't Rg ..."* Do you mean \$R_G\$ is short-circuited or open-circuited?

Comment: I can not identify Vin in this circuit. Where is it?

Comment: AC can flow through the gate, for the same reason it can flow through a capacitor.

Comment: I meant to write Vi instead of Vin, my bad.